# How to find out when was the last access to files of system?

Tags: security, operating-system, imageshack

How to find out when was the last access to files of system? Whether hacked or not? 
In general, how do I know which files I been hacked?

Answer (score 0):

There's a 'last access time' field in the `struct stat` data for a file.  However, a competent hacker knows that and can use the modern [`utimensat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimensat.html) function or the ancient and obsolescent [`utime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utime.html) function to set the last access time to any desired value.  It's hard to do it thoroughly, but hackers tend to be persistent types.